# querying inside $form->input() array

Tags: cakephp

echo $form->input('field', array(
                'type' => 'radio','legend'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],

```
            'separator' => '--separator--',
            'options' => array() 
        ));
```

How to query inside options to retrieve the options from the database for this corresponding Field..
like sending its attribute_id by $r['Attribute']['id']
  and fetching the cooresponding choices for that attribute..
 I have tried it with Ajax post 
 like

```
                             var ht = $.ajax({
                                              type: "GET",
                                              url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/viewChoices/"+attribute_id,
                                                                 async: false
                                                    }).responseText;


               var myObject = eval('(' + ht + ')');


var data = myObject;var j=0;
 $.map(data.choices, function(i){ j++; alert(i.choice);
```

return i.choice;});

And it returns me the choices in the i.choice..
but i dont know how to place this inside the options array...
Please suggest me....

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393164/fix-the-options-in-cakephp-form-field-of-type-radio-button

Answer (score 2):

you are not supposed to do that in view. do it in the controller and pass it to the view file.

Comment: hi i have used an ajax post and fetched that choices for that corresponding Attribute id but dont know how to fix it options